# How can I set Unity editor resolutions properly

Tags: unity-game-engine, editor

I'm new to unity and to be honest , it's resolution system looks very weird to me. Hope it will make sense once I get used to it. But for now, here is my problem:

I've set resolution under "build" tab to 1920x1080 (also tried with 16:9 ratio as well) . then I imported a 1920x1080 image. but when I try to display it, borders of the image doesn't show up. Clicking on play or pausing it doesn't solve it.

(approximately 20% of the image from all directions are not shown) .

what is the reason, and how can I solve this?

**edit**

Screenshots - intentionally draged sprite a little down so you can see canvas' borders.

ss1 https://prnt.sc/qj0pad

ss2 https://prnt.sc/qj0pty

ss3 https://prnt.sc/qj0pzs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to your canvas size.

When you drag and drop an image onto your scene, it will import it as a UI Image and create a Canvas to hold it. On the Canvas, the `UI Scale Mode` field of the `Canvas Scaler` component is by default on `Constant Pixel Size`. You'll want to change it to `Scale With Screen Size` and then put your resolution in the `Reference Resolution` field that appeared (which is 800x600 by default).

Comment: Thank you for the information but unfortunately it didn't change anything. it doesn't create canvas by default, I added it manually then made the image canvas' child. but still shown bigger than the canvas.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of the Canvas in the Inspector and of your hierarchy. A screenshot of your image in the Inspector would also be useful.

Comment: provided as update to the post, if they are not what you're asking for or you want to see other parts, let me know

Comment: Your image is set as a sprite rather than as a UI element. This means that it's position in the world matters for the rendering. Instead, what you'll want to do is right click and click on UI > Image to create a UI Image. Then drag and drop your asset into the `Source Image` field of the Image Component and click on the `Set Native Size` button that appeared.